# bootsrap form submit button not working

Tags: php, html, css, form-submit

The following code gives a signup form that i created but unfortunately the submit buttons do not work i read some previous stack overflow articles and made changes but it does not work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
  <title>Arsiri Textile </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basic.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">




<div class="header" style="height:60px;background:#330d00;width:1350px">


      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">ARSIRI TEXTILE |</a>


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Signup</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>


<div class="image" style="height:530px; width:1350px" >
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading" style="background:#330d00;">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Customer Registration</h3><br>
 </div>
  <div class="panel-body" >
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="signup.php" method="post" > 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="firstname">
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="lastname">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name" name="emailaddress">
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact No.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name" name="contactno">
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
 <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" class="form-control" name="address"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm password
    </label>
       <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpass" name="cpassword"><br>
    </div>
  </div>



</form>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow:hidden;text-align:left;">   

    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type=submit name=submit value=Submit >
<input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel>

    </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</div>




<div class="footer " style="background:#330d00; height:60px ;width:1350px ">
 <p align="center" > Asiri all rights reserved</p>
</div>
```

The signupaction.php script is as follows

```
<?php

//importing db.php in the includes folder
require("includes/db.php");


$fname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lname=$_POST["lastname"];
$email=$_POST["emailaddress"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$contact=$_POST["contactno"];


$password=$_POST["password"];
$cpassword=$_POST["cpassword"];



$sql="INSERT INTO signup (FName,LName,Address,Contact,Email,Password,CPassword) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address','$contact','$email','$password',$cpassword')";



$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if(!$result){
    echo "Unsuccessful signup";
}
else{
    echo "Successful signup";
}




?>
```

Please help me to correct this! When i click the submit button there is no change in the URL so i think the pproblem is in the signupform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="signup.php" method="post" >
```

action="signup.php" will redirect the form to the page signup.php
it seems you want it to redirect somewhere else?

You also probably want the submit button inside your form, not outside of it?

```
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow:hidden;text-align:left;">   

    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type=submit name=submit value=Submit >
<input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanx alot now the form is working but unfortunately i get the error "Undefined index: address in H:\xampnew\htdocs\phpfinal\signupaction.php on line 10" how can i coreect this?

Comment: check your variables and sql

Comment: yep it was aso corrected but unfortunately though there is no error now i get the message unsuccessful signup because the query fails :(