# Form submitting but mysql query not properly functioning

Tags: php, html, sql, form-submit

The following code gives a signup form that i created but unfortunately though it works the mysql query fails and returns the error message unsuccessfull signup! how can i correct this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
      <title>Arsiri Textile </title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
  <title>Arsiri Textile </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basic.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">




<div class="header" style="height:60px;background:#330d00;width:1350px">


      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">ARSIRI TEXTILE |</a>


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Signup</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>


<div class="image" style="height:530px; width:1350px" >
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading" style="background:#330d00;">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Customer Registration</h3><br>
 </div>
  <div class="panel-body" >
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="signupaction.php" method="post" > 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="firstname" required>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="lastname" required>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
           <textarea class="form-control" class="form-control" name="address"></textarea>

    </div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact No.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="name" name="contactno" required>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name" name="emailaddress" required>
    </div>
  </div>





    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="password" required>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm password
    </label>
       <div class="col-sm-10" style="width:300px">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpass" name="cpassword" required><br>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow:hidden;text-align:left;">   

    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type=submit name=submit value=Submit >
<input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel>

    </div>
</form>





    </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</div>




<div class="footer " style="background:#330d00; height:60px ;width:1350px ">
 <p align="center" > Asiri all rights reserved</p>
</div>
```

The relevant php script(ignupaction.php) for the above html form is as follows

```
<?php

//importing db.php in the includes folder

require("includes/db.php");


$fname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lname=$_POST["lastname"];

$address=$_POST["address"];
$contact=$_POST["contactno"];
$email=$_POST["emailaddress"];

$password=$_POST["password"];
$cpassword=$_POST["cpassword"];



$sql="INSERT INTO `signup`  VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address','$contact','$email','$password',$cpassword')";



$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if(!$result){
    echo "Unsuccessful signup";
}
else{
    echo "Successful signup";
}




?>
```

when the form is submitted it returns unsuccessful signup! how can i correect this?

Comment: you need to use proper error handling via php and the query and you have one right here `,$cpassword')`. It's an (off-topic) typo.

Comment: Perhaps turn on error handling and echo the error(s)?

Comment: Perhaps the missing quote is the problem? '$password',>>>>$cpassword'

Comment: You're wide open for SQL injection. Take advantage of prepared statements and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), and you can fix those pesky quoting issues.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Instead of just `echo "Unsuccessful signup";`, output something useful. Have a look at [`mysqli_error()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: _An observation:_ You ask for password confirmation, but you never compare it with the password?

Comment: You did the same typo in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40677881/  `'$password',$cpassword')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $sql="INSERT INTO `signup`  VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address','$contact','$email','$password',$cpassword')";

you are missing a ' on the last variable. you have '$password',$cpassword'  <----- missing '. Also change the ticks around 'signup'.

Try this :

> $sql="INSERT INTO 'signup'  VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address','$contact','$email','$password','$cpassword')";